# Angular: how to correctly enforce a promise to complete before navigation with routerLink?

Tags: angular, promise, async-await, angular-router

New to angular development and need some insight on how to get async/await to work.

I have a button that makes an API call and then loads the next page.  I need to wait to load the next page until the API call is complete.  Problem is it's not working.

HTML Button:

```
<button type="button" [routerLink]="['../Review']" (click)=nextPage()">Next</button>
```

nextPage() Function:

```
private async nextPage(){ 
        await this.practiceData.put_Practice(this.practice.practiceId,this.practice).toPromise();
      });
    }
  }
```

http functions:

```
put_Practice(practiceId: number, practice: Practice)
  {
    return this.httpClient.put(this.baseUrl + '/Practice/' + practiceId, practice, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

Comment: Please specify *what* is not working. Does it fail to compile? Do you get any error message?

Comment: `[routerLink]="['../Review']"` triggers a route change immediately when the click event is fired. You have to use the `Router` service to change the route after the promise has resolved. So update `nextPage()` to call `then()` and perform a route change afterwards.

Comment: @churill Sure, The next page loads before the PUT api call is complete.  That page is doing a http GET request for the user to review.  So they are reviewing old data since it loaded the page before the PUT completed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the click event handler bounded by the `RouterLink` directive is triggered before the promise completes.
You will need to refactor your code in order to trigger the *navigation* manually:

```
<button type="button" (click)=nextPage()">Next</button>

import {Router,ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

export class MyComponent {
   constructor(private readonly router: Router, private readonly route: ActivatedRoute){}

   async nextPage(){
      await this.practiceData.put_Practice(this.practice.practiceId,this.practice).toPromise();
      await this.router.navigate(["../Review"],{relativeTo: this.route});
      // or without async/await you can simply chain the promises
   }
}
```

Comment: Great concise and correct answer.  Thanks so much, this was a huge help.  I had assumed the problem was the async and not the routerlink.  Answer Accepted